# How to print only a certain number of bytes with C-printf() with Nasm assembler?

Tags: c, assembly, printing, printf, nasm

I'm trying to print only a certain numbers of bytes of a string with printf of C. I'm working with Nasm assembler. The problem is that i can't use for example "%.5s", because the number of bytes I need to print changes.
I have something like this:

```
extern printf

section .data     
format:   db "%s",10,0      
msg:      db    "0123456789ABCDEF"

section .text   
    global main    
    main:

push msg       
push format                 
call printf           
add esp,12      

mov eax,1           
mov ebx,0        
int 80h
```

Comment: Why should this be an assembly question? You are using a C function, so the solution is the same as it would be in C. Using assembler is just an uninmportant detail.

Comment: But in C i only must write printf("(%.*s)", n, string); where n is the number of bytes i want to print, but in assembler I cant do that.

Comment: why can't you do that in assembler?

Comment: It`s not a assembler instruction.

Comment: @olmanqj: It's just pushing another argument on the stack before the `printf` call, just as you did with `msg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*printf("(%.*s)", n, string);*" in assembly:

```
...
format: db "%.*s",10,0
n:      dd 5
...
push msg
push dword [n]
push format
call printf
add esp,12     ; 4 * count of pushes
```

Consider the "reverse" order of the pushes.

BTW: You forgot the last 0 in your msg.